# How does conditional type work in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-conditional-types

I came across conditional type in TypeScript and I found many vague definitions about its functionality in TypeScript.

Consider following conditional type as an example:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T

let MyType : NonNullable<string | null>;
```

[This post](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/conditional-types-in-typescript) is the first result when I search for condition type in TypeScript on google.

It defines `T extends U ? X : Y` conditional type as follows:

> In human language, this conditional type reads as follows: If the type
> T is assignable to the type U, select the type X; otherwise, select
> the type Y.

So applying this definition to our example I can say is (`string | null`) assignable to `null` type? The answer is no so `MyType` should be (`string | null`). **Which is wrong**

The other post [here](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/) defines it as follows which makes sense:

> Conditional types let you filter out particular members of a union
> type.

In this definition compiler checks for each possible type(lets call it `TT`) in union type T, if this type(`TT`) is assignable to `null` or `undefined` compiler filter them out in making definition for `MyType`.

These are my questions:

1. Which definition is correct?
2. Is there any better (and general) definition for conditional types in TypeScript?

Comment: Maybe this will help in understanding. Look union type `string | null` separately, can be considered as `NonNullable<string> | NonNullable<null>`, so we get `string | never` which is the same as `string`